# Не работает цикл elif

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Есть код на Python
Всё работает, кроме последнего `elif`
Помогите решить проблему

```
import re
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from first_project.project.design_project import Ui_MainWindow


class WayToTheDream(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('Way To The Dream!')
        self.setFixedSize(1010, 546)

        self.PolZhen.stateChanged.connect(self.calc_logic2)

    def calc_logic2(self, toggle):

        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.PolMuzh.setEnabled(False)
            list_tren = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7+']
            if self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Сидячий':
                if [self.ComboTrenirovki.currentText() == i for i in list_tren]:
                    string_vozrast = self.LineVozrast.text()
                    string_vozrast1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_vozrast)))))
                    if 7 <= string_vozrast1 < 112:
                        string_ves = self.LineVes.text()
                        string_ves1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_ves)))))
                        if 635 > string_ves1 >= 20:
                            string_rost = self.LineRost.text()
                            string_rost1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_rost)))))
                            if 272 > string_rost1 >= 55:
                                zhen_rashod = (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (
                                        5 * string_vozrast1) - 161
                                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(zhen_rashod * 1.2) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Слабый физ. труд':
                if [self.ComboTrenirovki.currentText() == i for i in list_tren]:
                    string_vozrast = self.LineVozrast.text()
                    string_vozrast1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_vozrast)))))
                    if 7 <= string_vozrast1 < 112:
                        string_ves = self.LineVes.text()
                        string_ves1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_ves)))))
                        if 635 > string_ves1 >= 20:
                            string_rost = self.LineRost.text()
                            string_rost1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_rost)))))
                            if 272 > string_rost1 >= 55:
                                zhen_rashod = (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (
                                        5 * string_vozrast1) - 161
                                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(zhen_rashod * 1.375) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Преобладает физ. труд':
                if [self.ComboTrenirovki.currentText() == i for i in list_tren]:
                    string_vozrast = self.LineVozrast.text()
                    string_vozrast1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_vozrast)))))
                    if 7 <= string_vozrast1 < 112:
                        string_ves = self.LineVes.text()
                        string_ves1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_ves)))))
                        if 635 > string_ves1 >= 20:
                            string_rost = self.LineRost.text()
                            string_rost1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_rost)))))
                            if 272 > string_rost1 >= 55:
                                zhen_rashod = (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (
                                        5 * string_vozrast1) - 161
                                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(zhen_rashod * 1.55) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Тяжёлый физ. труд':
                if [self.ComboTrenirovki.currentText() == i for i in list_tren]:
                    string_vozrast = self.LineVozrast.text()
                    string_vozrast1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_vozrast)))))
                    if 7 <= string_vozrast1 < 112:
                        string_ves = self.LineVes.text()
                        string_ves1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_ves)))))
                        if 635 > string_ves1 >= 20:
                            string_rost = self.LineRost.text()
                            string_rost1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_rost)))))
                            if 272 > string_rost1 >= 55:
                                zhen_rashod = (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (
                                        5 * string_vozrast1) - 161
                                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(zhen_rashod * 1.725) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Очень тяжёлый физ. труд':
                if [self.ComboTrenirovki.currentText() == i for i in list_tren]:
                    string_vozrast = self.LineVozrast.text()
                    string_vozrast1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_vozrast)))))
                    if 7 <= string_vozrast1 < 112:
                        string_ves = self.LineVes.text()
                        string_ves1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_ves)))))
                        if 635 > string_ves1 >= 20:
                            string_rost = self.LineRost.text()
                            string_rost1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_rost)))))
                            if 272 > string_rost1 >= 55:
                                zhen_rashod = (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (
                                        5 * string_vozrast1) - 161
                                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(zhen_rashod * 1.9) + ' ккал/сут.')
                            elif 7 > string_vozrast1 > 112 or 635 < string_ves1 < 20 or 272 < string_rost1 < 55:
                                abshibka = 'Данные введены неверно!'
                                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(abshibka)
        else:
            self.PolMuzh.setEnabled(True)
            self.LineVivodCalc.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = WayToTheDream()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

- ComboFizAkt - `ComboBox`, в котором несколько вариантов выбора
- LineVozrast, LineVes, LineRost - `lineedit`, в которые вводятся данные
- LineVivodCalc - `lineedit` в котором выводятся данные

**design_project.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1010, 546)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #F0F0F0;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.ViborPola = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.ViborPola.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 320, 81, 51))
        self.ViborPola.setObjectName("ViborPola")
        self.PolMuzh = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.PolMuzh.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 320, 70, 17))
        self.PolMuzh.setObjectName("PolMuzh")
        self.PolZhen = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.PolZhen.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 350, 70, 17))
        self.PolZhen.setObjectName("PolZhen")
        self.UkazatVozrast = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.UkazatVozrast.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 150, 81, 51))
        self.UkazatVozrast.setObjectName("UkazatVozrast")
        self.LineVozrast = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.LineVozrast.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 150, 71, 51))
        self.LineVozrast.setObjectName("LineVozrast")
        self.UkazatVes = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.UkazatVes.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 200, 81, 51))
        self.UkazatVes.setObjectName("UkazatVes")
        self.LineVes = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.LineVes.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 200, 71, 51))
        self.LineVes.setObjectName("LineVes")
        self.UkazatRost = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.UkazatRost.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 250, 81, 51))
        self.UkazatRost.setObjectName("UkazatRost")
        self.LineRost = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.LineRost.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 250, 71, 51))
        self.LineRost.setObjectName("LineRost")
        self.LvlFizAkt = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.LvlFizAkt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 50, 171, 21))
        self.LvlFizAkt.setObjectName("LvlFizAkt")
        self.ComboFizAkt = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.ComboFizAkt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 70, 171, 22))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setObjectName("ComboFizAkt")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.KolvoTrenirovok = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.KolvoTrenirovok.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 100, 171, 21))
        self.KolvoTrenirovok.setObjectName("KolvoTrenirovok")
        self.ComboTrenirovki = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 120, 171, 22))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setObjectName("ComboTrenirovki")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.LineVivodCalc = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.LineVivodCalc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 370, 171, 91))
        self.LineVivodCalc.setObjectName("LineVivodCalc")        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1010, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.ViborPola.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пол"))
    self.PolMuzh.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Мужской"))
    self.PolZhen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Женский"))
    self.UkazatVozrast.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Возраст"))
    self.UkazatVes.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вес"))
    self.UkazatRost.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Рост"))
    self.LvlFizAkt.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Уровень физической активности:"))
    self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Сидячий"))
    self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Слабый физ. труд"))
    self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Преобладает физ. труд"))
    self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Тяжёлый физ. труд"))
    self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "Очень тяжёлый физ. труд"))
    self.KolvoTrenirovok.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Кол-во тренировок в неделю:"))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick готово.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте `design_project.py`

Comment: @S.Nick готово.

Comment: это условие всегда ложное `7 > string_vozrast1 > 112` . Надо ли еще что-то смотреть?

Comment: @S.Nick если ввести неверные данные, то в LineVivodCalc ничего не выведет

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте ваши условия на корректность!

Я не понимаю, что значит: "если ввести неверные данные, то в LineVivodCalc ничего не выведет".

```
import re
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

#from first_project.project.design_project import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1010, 546)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #F0F0F0;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.ViborPola = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.ViborPola.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 320, 81, 51))
        self.ViborPola.setObjectName("ViborPola")
        self.PolMuzh = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.PolMuzh.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 320, 70, 17))
        self.PolMuzh.setObjectName("PolMuzh")
        self.PolZhen = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.PolZhen.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 350, 70, 17))
        self.PolZhen.setObjectName("PolZhen")
        self.UkazatVozrast = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.UkazatVozrast.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 150, 81, 51))
        self.UkazatVozrast.setObjectName("UkazatVozrast")
        self.LineVozrast = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.LineVozrast.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 150, 71, 51))
        self.LineVozrast.setObjectName("LineVozrast")
        self.UkazatVes = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.UkazatVes.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 200, 81, 51))
        self.UkazatVes.setObjectName("UkazatVes")
        self.LineVes = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.LineVes.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 200, 71, 51))
        self.LineVes.setObjectName("LineVes")
        self.UkazatRost = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.UkazatRost.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(790, 250, 81, 51))
        self.UkazatRost.setObjectName("UkazatRost")
        self.LineRost = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.LineRost.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 250, 71, 51))
        self.LineRost.setObjectName("LineRost")
        self.LvlFizAkt = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.LvlFizAkt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 50, 171, 21))
        self.LvlFizAkt.setObjectName("LvlFizAkt")
        self.ComboFizAkt = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.ComboFizAkt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 70, 171, 22))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setObjectName("ComboFizAkt")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.ComboFizAkt.addItem("")
        self.KolvoTrenirovok = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.KolvoTrenirovok.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 100, 171, 21))
        self.KolvoTrenirovok.setObjectName("KolvoTrenirovok")
        self.ComboTrenirovki = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 120, 171, 22))
        self.ComboTrenirovki.setObjectName("ComboTrenirovki")
        '''
        # убрал
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItem("")
        '''
        self.LineVivodCalc = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.LineVivodCalc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 370, 171, 91))
        self.LineVivodCalc.setObjectName("LineVivodCalc")        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1010, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.ViborPola.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пол"))
        self.PolMuzh.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Мужской"))
        self.PolZhen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Женский"))
        self.UkazatVozrast.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Возраст"))
        self.UkazatVes.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вес"))
        self.UkazatRost.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Рост"))
        self.LvlFizAkt.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Уровень физической активности:"))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Сидячий"))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Слабый физ. труд"))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Преобладает физ. труд"))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Тяжёлый физ. труд"))
        self.ComboFizAkt.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "Очень тяжёлый физ. труд"))
        self.KolvoTrenirovok.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Кол-во тренировок в неделю:"))
    

class WayToTheDream(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('Way To The Dream!')
        self.setFixedSize(1010, 546)
#+++        
        self.list_tren = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7+']                 # +++
        self.ComboTrenirovki.addItems(self.list_tren)                              # +++

        self.PolZhen.stateChanged.connect(self.calc_logic2)
        self.PolMuzh.stateChanged.connect(self.calc_logic1)                        # +++
        
    def calc_logic1(self, toggle):                                                 # +++
        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.PolZhen.setEnabled(False) 
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, "Информационное сообщение", "У вас нет логики расчетов для мужчин."
            )
        else:
            self.PolZhen.setEnabled(True)
            self.LineVivodCalc.clear()                    

    def calc_logic2(self, toggle):
        if toggle == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.PolMuzh.setEnabled(False)
#            list_tren = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7+']                     # ---
            if self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Сидячий':
                if [self.ComboTrenirovki.currentText() == i for i in self.list_tren]:  # + self.
                    string_vozrast = self.LineVozrast.text()
                    string_vozrast1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_vozrast)))))
                    if 7 <= string_vozrast1 < 112:
                        string_ves = self.LineVes.text()
                        string_ves1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_ves)))))
                        if 635 > string_ves1 >= 20:
                            string_rost = self.LineRost.text()
                            string_rost1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_rost)))))
                            if 272 > string_rost1 >= 55:
                                zhen_rashod = (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (
                                        5 * string_vozrast1) - 161
                                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(zhen_rashod * 1.2) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Слабый физ. труд':
                if [self.ComboTrenirovki.currentText() == i for i in self.list_tren]:
                    string_vozrast = self.LineVozrast.text()
                    string_vozrast1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_vozrast)))))
                    if 7 <= string_vozrast1 < 112:
                        string_ves = self.LineVes.text()
                        string_ves1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_ves)))))
                        if 635 > string_ves1 >= 20:
                            string_rost = self.LineRost.text()
                            string_rost1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_rost)))))
                            if 272 > string_rost1 >= 55:
                                zhen_rashod = (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (
                                        5 * string_vozrast1) - 161
                                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(zhen_rashod * 1.375) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Преобладает физ. труд':
                if [self.ComboTrenirovki.currentText() == i for i in self.list_tren]:
                    string_vozrast = self.LineVozrast.text()
                    string_vozrast1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_vozrast)))))
                    if 7 <= string_vozrast1 < 112:
                        string_ves = self.LineVes.text()
                        string_ves1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_ves)))))
                        if 635 > string_ves1 >= 20:
                            string_rost = self.LineRost.text()
                            string_rost1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_rost)))))
                            if 272 > string_rost1 >= 55:
                                zhen_rashod = (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (
                                        5 * string_vozrast1) - 161
                                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(zhen_rashod * 1.55) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Тяжёлый физ. труд':
                if [self.ComboTrenirovki.currentText() == i for i in self.list_tren]:
                    string_vozrast = self.LineVozrast.text()
                    string_vozrast1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_vozrast)))))
                    if 7 <= string_vozrast1 < 112:
                        string_ves = self.LineVes.text()
                        string_ves1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_ves)))))
                        if 635 > string_ves1 >= 20:
                            string_rost = self.LineRost.text()
                            string_rost1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_rost)))))
                            if 272 > string_rost1 >= 55:
                                zhen_rashod = (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (
                                        5 * string_vozrast1) - 161
                                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(zhen_rashod * 1.725) + ' ккал/сут.')
            elif self.ComboFizAkt.currentText() == 'Очень тяжёлый физ. труд':
                if [self.ComboTrenirovki.currentText() == i for i in self.list_tren]:
                    string_vozrast = self.LineVozrast.text()
                    string_vozrast1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_vozrast)))))
                    if 7 <= string_vozrast1 < 112:
                        string_ves = self.LineVes.text()
                        string_ves1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_ves)))))
                        if 635 > string_ves1 >= 20:
                            string_rost = self.LineRost.text()
                            string_rost1 = int("0" + "".join(list(map(str, re.findall(r'\d+', string_rost)))))
                            if 272 > string_rost1 >= 55:
                                zhen_rashod = (10 * string_ves1) + (6.25 * string_rost1) - (
                                        5 * string_vozrast1) - 161
                                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(str(zhen_rashod * 1.9) + ' ккал/сут.')

###                                 эти условия всегда ложные        !!!                              
                            elif   7 > string_vozrast1 > 112 or \
                                 635 < string_ves1     <  20 or \
                                 272 < string_rost1    < 55:
                                abshibka = 'Данные введены неверно!'
                                self.LineVivodCalc.setText(abshibka)
        else:
            self.PolMuzh.setEnabled(True)
            self.LineVivodCalc.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = WayToTheDream()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]